# Server Hour considering another TZ as reference

Tags: date, go, timezone, php-carbon

I am trying to trigger a worker at certain hour. The thing is that I need to know what is the relative hour of the server for that hour. Clients want to trigger the worker at 8pm everyday in Los Angeles Time, so I have to make it the enough dynamic that it takes the server hour, calculate what is the equivalent for that hour in Los Angeles. I am also using carbon, but is there any built-in function for that? Or is there any know routine to deal with it?

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. Are you actually having a problem? This should be the default behavior, if you specify a timezone in your schedule. What actual problem are you facing?

Comment: I was looking for a built-in function to make that time transformation without make this manually, as it seems to be a common problem in many projects

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want a built-in function to do. I don't think you need a function, at all. You just need to parse the time in the proper time zone.

Comment: @Flimzybecause is easier, and is always the same, would be something like: hey give the local hour when in LA are 8pm

Comment: Because what is easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time.LoadLocation` and `time.In` are the two functions you need. The below code is copied and modified from `time.LoadLocation` example:

```
func main() {
    location, err := time.LoadLocation("America/Los_Angeles")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    timeInUTC := time.Date(2018, 8, 30, 12, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    fmt.Println(timeInUTC.In(location))

    now := time.Now()
    timeThere := time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day(), 8, 0, 0, 0, location)
    timeHere := timeThere.In(time.Now().Location())
    fmt.Println(timeHere)
}
```

Comment: This displays `timeInUTC` in LA. But the OP needs essentially the opposite: A time specified in LA time needs to trigger an event in UTC (or server time).

Comment: Edited the answer to include both.